# CardView with support library in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-cardview

I would like to use CardView in Eclipse/ADT with the v7 support libraries. So far I have:

1. Imported appcompat-v7 into the workspace (from sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat)
2. Imported cardview into the workspace (from sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview)
3. Set the appcompat-v7 as a reference library in the cardview library
4. In my project, added both libraries as reference libraries, and added cardview.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to the build path

Yet, I receive "Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView" if I run the app (It allows me to install it, but it cannot be opened).

What have I done wrong? What might be my problem?

Comment: Why not use Android Studio?

Comment: Because using Saros it is very easy to collaborate, and every software are written together - so it would be pretty hard to continue the work together with AS. But if you know any good collaboration tool (real-time changes would be appreciated) then I'd be truly happy!

Comment: Right click on project -->java build path --> order and expert --> unchecked your external library if you have any and clean your project